# Difference between a scripting language vs programming language?

Tags: scripting

Please, can anyone explain to me the diff between these two types of language?
And, can one language be these two types at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, most scripting languages are programming languages, but not all programming languages are scripting languages.

The theoretical difference between the two is that scripting languages do not require a compilation step and are instead interpreted. For example, a C or C++ program normally needs to be compiled before running, whereas a scripting language like JavaScript or PHP does not need to be compiled.

Here are some of the main differences between scripting languages and programming languages.

1. Programming language code, when compiled, creates executable files in binary code, also called .exe files, which take up memory, whereas scripting languages do not create executable .exe files.
2. User interface design and graphical design are often partially supported by programming languages, whereas user interface design, data types, and graphical design are all greatly facilitated by scripting languages.
3. Programming languages are designed to facilitate full-fledged software development, while scripting languages are used to assist programming languages and make coding easier and faster. Scripting languages are generally used for open source projects and web development.
4. Programming languages are self-executable while scripting languages require a host.
5. Programming languages are compressed into small packages that do not need to be interpreted by another language or application, while scripting languages are written in one language and interpreted in another program. For example, JavaScript must be embedded in HTML, which is then interpreted by a web browser.

Comment: "JavaScript must be embedded in HTML"

Are you sure about this?